# Showing that a function is constant

Tags: calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable at any point. Assume that  $x \cdot f_x(x,y) + y \cdot f_y(x,y) = 0$ for each point $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Show that $f$ is constant in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Is the following proof correct:
Let $(x_0,y_0) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and define $g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ by $g(t)=(tx_0,ty_0)$. $g$ is differentiable at any point so by the chain rule we have $(f \circ g)'(t) = D_{f \circ g} = D_f(g(t)) \cdot D_g(t) = x_0f_x(tx_0,ty_0) + y_0f_y(tx_0,ty_0)$. For $t>0$ we have $(f \circ g)'(t) = \frac1t(tx_0f_x(tx_0,ty_0) + ty_0f_y(tx_0,ty_0)) = 0$. So $f \circ g$ is constant for $t>0$ assume $f \circ g = c$. $f$ is differentiable and thus continuous so we have $c = \lim_{t \to 0^+} f(tx_0,ty_0) = f(0,0)$.

So if $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ we can write $(x,y) = (tx_0,ty_0)$ for $(x_0,y_0) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $t>0$ and by what we showed $f(x,y) = f(tx_0,ty_0) = f(0,0)$.

Comment: +1, very well thought out question. I wish everyone asked questions like that :-)

Comment: You will certainly have to exclude the case $x_0=y_0=0$ since $g$ would be constant in that case, masking the behavior of $f$

Comment: But it's still correct in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof appears correct to me. If I were writing it, I'd slightly change the phrasing at three points:

First, I'd say "Let $(x_0, y_0)$ be any point of $R^2$ except the origin, and define ..."

I'd say that because you only use this claim when the point isn't the origin, and as another commenter pointed out, in the case where it *is* the origin, your further statements seem to say nothing. So avoid confusing the reader. :)

Second, I'd say "For $T \ne 0$" rather than "For $t > 0$".

Why? Because all you need is non-zero-ness. It's true that soon you'll take a one-sided limit, but when *I* read the proof, I was puzzled and thought "isn't this true for $t < 0$ as well?"

Third, I'd say "So $f \circ g$ is constant (although the constant may depend on $(x_0, y_0)$). For $t > 0$, assume that $f \circ g = c_{(x_0, y_0)}$. We'll now show that this is in fact independent of $(x_0, y_0)$."

The two key things here are (1) splitting into two sentences, and (2) explaining the subtlety, so that your reader knows where you're headed.

In fact, I'd start the proof by saying "The broad idea is to show that (i) $f$ is constant along rays through the origin, and (ii) that the constant value is the same for any two rays, namely $f(0,0)$."

Comment: I'm troubled by the fact that $c$ really depends on $g$. Is radial approach good enough?

Comment: If the function is constant on radii from the origin (as established by the derivative argument) and the value on each radius is the same (because it's always the same as $f(0,0)$ by continuity), then the function is constant on the plane.  I don't see any problem.

Comment: @John I really appreciate your helpful answer. But I just wanted to be sure: is the proof (as I wrote it) formally correct?

Comment: I believe that it's correct, yes. But this sentence"So f∘g is constant for t>0 assume f∘g=c ...", is run-on, and therefore not completely right (because it doesn't make sense as a sentence), even though just about anyone can understand what you were trying to say.